# Floating point vs Binary parameters in Neural Networks?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network

What is the reasoning that floating-point parameters are preferred over binary parameters?

Is there a specific limitation of binary parameters?

Is there something that is not possible using binary parameters, and we need floating point parameters (and gradient descent) to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

A function from a binary parameters to the loss is non differentiable. Or rather gradients are 0 everywhere, which means **you cannot** learn it with gradient descent. You can do various hacks to do so, but it will not be the "standard gradient descent". And gradient descent is the core learning method for neural networks, thus you are left with either a bit of alchemy (hacking things which are not mathematically sound) or very inefficient alternatives (e.g. genetic algorithms). Overall the standard practise is to always train in proper, smooth space (e.g. floats) and then, if needed - binarise / discretise your model.